# Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I try to add some kind of remember me functionality in react native app. For login to app, user scan a qr code and if that scanned value is in a specific array then user logged in.

My goal is once user login to app can never logout even if app closed too.So there is no logout button. For that purpose I add AsyncStorage to my login page.

I tried to achieve that If `isLoggedIn` is true, navigate to home page else normal login page with scanner to read qr code value. First I got the error render nothing, so I add return(null); at the end. I do not know this was a good idea or not but I believe that never reach that return since both if and else have their own return. My problem is I got the error;

> Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

But I have no idea what is wrong with this code. I am really new to React Native so I could not find out where is the problem. Can you help me to fix the error?

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Button,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Alert,
} from 'react-native';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';
import {
  BarCodeScanner
} from 'expo-barcode-scanner';
import axios from 'axios';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

export default function Giris({navigation}) {
    
    const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
    const [scanned, setScanned] = useState(false);

    var giris_kontrol = false;

    AsyncStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn').then((value) => {
      if(value && value === 'YES') {

        AsyncStorage.getItem('kullaniciAd').then((value) => {
          if(value !== null) {
            data = value;
            navigation.navigate('AnaSayfa',{data:data});
          } 
        });
        
      } else {

        useEffect(() => {
          (async () => {
            const { status } = await BarCodeScanner.requestPermissionsAsync();
            setHasPermission(status === 'granted');
          })();
        }, []);
      
        const handleBarCodeScanned = ({ type, data }) => {
          setScanned(true);
          
          const url_kullanicilar = "--url here--";
          
          axios.get(url_kullanicilar) 
            .then(res => {
              var kullanici_sayisi = res.data.items.length;
              //console.log(res.data.items[13].kullanici_kodu);    
              
              
              for(i =0; i<kullanici_sayisi; i++ ){
                //console.log(res.data.items[i].kullanici_kodu)
    
                if(data == res.data.items[i].kullanici_kodu){ 
                  giris_kontrol=true;


                  AsyncStorage.setItem('kullaniciAd', data).then(()=>{
                    AsyncStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn', 'YES');
                  });

                  navigation.navigate('AnaSayfa',{data:data}); 
                }
              }
              if(giris_kontrol == false){
                //Alert.alert(`Giriş yetkiniz yoktur.`); 
                Alert.alert(
                  "Giriş Yapılamadı",
                  `Giriş yetkiniz yoktur.`
                );
              }
    
            })
    
          //10 sn for rescan
          setTimeout(function () {
            setScanned(false);
          }, 10000); 
    
          //setScanned(false);
          
        };
      
        if (hasPermission === null) {
          return <Text>Requesting for camera permission</Text>;
        }
        if (hasPermission === false) {
    
          return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
        }
      
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <BarCodeScanner
              onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : handleBarCodeScanned}
              style={StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}
            />
           
          </View>
        );
      }
    });

  return(
    null
  );  
  
  }
  
  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      flexDirection: 'column',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    
    },
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many mistakes in your code. the first one you have out the closing tag  `});` of `AsyncStorage` in the wrong place. the second and third that the `data` and `i` are not defined. Here is the code you can run.

import 'react-native-gesture-handler';

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Button,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Alert,
} from 'react-native';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';
import {
  BarCodeScanner
} from 'expo-barcode-scanner';
import axios from 'axios';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

export default function Giris({navigation}) {
    
    const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
    const [scanned, setScanned] = useState(false);
    let data = null;
    var giris_kontrol = false;

    AsyncStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn').then((value) => {
      if(value && value === 'YES') {

        AsyncStorage.getItem('kullaniciAd').then((value) => {
          if(value !== null) {
            data = value;
            navigation.navigate('AnaSayfa',{data:data});
          } 
        });
        
      } 
      })

        useEffect(() => {
          (async () => {
            const { status } = await BarCodeScanner.requestPermissionsAsync();
            setHasPermission(status === 'granted');
          })();
        }, []);
      
        const handleBarCodeScanned = ({ type, data }) => {
          setScanned(true);
          
          const url_kullanicilar = "--url here--";
          
          axios.get(url_kullanicilar) 
            .then(res => {
              var kullanici_sayisi = res.data.items.length;
              //console.log(res.data.items[13].kullanici_kodu);    
              
              
              for(let i =0; i<kullanici_sayisi; i++ ){
                //console.log(res.data.items[i].kullanici_kodu)
    
                if(data == res.data.items[i].kullanici_kodu){ 
                  giris_kontrol=true;


                  AsyncStorage.setItem('kullaniciAd', data).then(()=>{
                    AsyncStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn', 'YES');
                  });

                  navigation.navigate('AnaSayfa',{data:data}); 
                }
              }
              if(giris_kontrol == false){
                //Alert.alert(`Giriş yetkiniz yoktur.`); 
                Alert.alert(
                  "Giriş Yapılamadı",
                  `Giriş yetkiniz yoktur.`
                );
              }
    
            })
    
          //10 sn for rescan
          setTimeout(function () {
            setScanned(false);
          }, 10000); 
    
          //setScanned(false);
          
        };
      
        if (hasPermission === null) {
          return <Text>Requesting for camera permission</Text>;
        }
        if (hasPermission === false) {
    
          return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
        }
      
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <BarCodeScanner
              onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : handleBarCodeScanned}
              style={StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}
            />
           
          </View>
        ); 
  
  }
  
  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      flexDirection: 'column',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    
    },
  });
```

Comment: I tried it and works perfectly. Thank you for your help, it saves a lot of time.